# How to avoid duplicate entry in the database if the data is submitted from two users at the same time?

Tags: php, database, mysqli

My question is a little bit confusing, i understand that my question may sound similar to other questions here. I have a form that is numbered and increase by 1 depending what is the last value in the database. 
For example in the database:

```
ID | ApplicationNumber
 1 |    1
 2 |    2
```

So if the user will generate another form it will display as: `Application Number 3`. And it will be save in the database as application number 3. But what if there are two users who will submit the form at the same time? Both are filling up the form numbered as: `Application Number 3` and before my `INSERT INTO`i perform the query of looking the last value in the database so i can `+1` to the value of Application Number value before submitting it to the database. I let two users submit the form at the same time and what i received in the database is like this:

```
 ID | ApplicationNumber
 1 |    1
 2 |    2
 3 |    3
 4 |    3
```

My query for getting the last value and BEFORE inserting something to the database:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT table1.ApplicationNumber FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.AdminID = table2.AdminID AND table2.Username = '$user' ORDER BY table1.ApplicationNumber DESC LIMIT 1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {



    $aNumber = $row['ApplicationNumber'] + 1;
}
```

Comment: These solutions can be helpful for you `insert.. on duplicate key update` or `insert ignore` see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html   &   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Comment: Question is what you trying to achieve. Do you want to show some kind of error to the second user. Or do you want to have it silently add +1 to the updated count in this kind of situation?

Comment: @Nagh i just want to avoid duplicate ApplicationNumber in the database. Showing error is  not really necessary though. I dont know how to work on it because it is from two users,  i guess it is different from one user pressing the "submit" button twice, because i can avoid that, but how about from two users submitting a form at the same time? Is it possible to hold one form to be submitted if another form is being submitted? it doesnt sound right and it is not efficient.

Comment: @rigorcadiz there are different ways to achieve what you want, its all depends on how do you want to react on this kind of situation?

Comment: @BeingSunny ill check the link first. I dont really want to update the value of the database if it has the same Application Number because both users fill the form differently, its just the application number IF the form is submitted at the same time from two users.  And i guess submitting the form at the same time is ony like 2% but it will destroy the numbering in the system if i cant find a solution for that. :)

Comment: @Nagh maybe i will just perform another query after the INSERT to check if there are duplicates in the ApplicationNumber in each row in the database? And +1 to the last ApplicationNumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm getting you right there are few straightforward options from the database point of view:

1. Use [autoincrement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html) for the ApplicationNumber column in mysql
2. Create [Unique-key constraint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/constraint-primary-key.html) for this column and handle this error somehow
3. Also you can just [LOCK the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) before select, so you have exclusive access to the data. Beware, you should especially care for unlock and understand that other users won't be able to use this table, while lock in effect.

Comment: how about my ID column should i discard that and just use application number instead as the key? My iD column is already auto incremented.

Comment: @rigorcadiz its tottaly up to you, you can use both or just throw away key, if ApplicationNumber actually serves as your table's primary key.